# Overlay boundary plots on ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, ggmap

I'm trying to overlay a [shapefile with boundaries of NTAs](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/2010-Neighborhood-Tabulation-Areas-NTAs-/cpf4-rkhq) in New York on a ggmap. My code is:

```
nta_shp <- st_read('geo_export_de8807a0-e424-4399-95ee-3f8bcc187b7a.shp')
nta_shp <- nta_shp[nta_shp$boro_name=="Manhattan",]

mh_bb <- getbb("manhattan new york usa")
mh_bb[1] <- -74.04
mh_bb[2] <- 40.65
mh_map <- get_map(mh_bb, source="google", zoom=12, scale=2)
ggmap(mh_map) + 
 geom_sf(data=nta_shp, aes(geometry=geometry), color="#5e5f61", alpha=.2)
```

However, I get the error: `Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one. Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lon' not found`

How can I plot the polygons in my shapefile (just the boundaries) with ggmap?

`nta_shp` is as below:

```
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 7 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -74.01638 ymin: 40.71136 xmax: -73.9376 ymax: 40.81809
Geodetic CRS:  WGS84(DD)
   boro_code boro_name county_fip ntacode                                ntaname shape_area
8          1 Manhattan        061    MN12                        Upper West Side   34379942
17         1 Manhattan        061    MN21                               Gramercy    7526916
33         1 Manhattan        061    MN32                              Yorkville   13648288
37         1 Manhattan        061    MN09                    Morningside Heights   20153942
38         1 Manhattan        061    MN11                   Central Harlem South   14441228
44         1 Manhattan        061    MN24 SoHo-TriBeCa-Civic Center-Little Italy   25032679
   shape_leng                       geometry
8    29160.21 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.96003 4...
17   12096.89 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.98239 4...
33   18190.98 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.93805 4...
37   20749.50 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.9521 40...
38   16624.46 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.94177 4...
44   26855.03 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.9926 40...
```

Comment: `geom_sf(data=dnta, ...` does object "dnta" exist (and is a proper spatial dataframe), or is that a typo? If it does exist, please provide it, or a sufficient part of it, along with any other information necessary for a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I'm using ```nta_shp```. I've added a link to the shapefiles and copied a data extract.

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine if I use `ggplot() + geom_sf(...)` instead of `ggmap()`.  `get_map` for use with `ggmap` throws an error, though, because I haven't got an API key: ```Error in `get_googlemap()`: ! Google now requires an API key``` . Could that be the actual issue?

Comment: No, I did have an API key but I figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```r
inherit.aes=FALSE
```

as this:

```r
ggmap(mh_map) + 
   geom_sf(data=nta_shp, aes(geometry=geometry), color="#5e5f61", 
   alpha=.2, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```